# Ktor force refresh cache-control endpoint

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I've started using Ktor (recently updated to 2.0.0) on a new android project, to consume an API endpoint configured to have the `Cache-Control: max-age=3600` header on their responses.

I've set up my client as specified on Ktor's [docs](https://ktor.io/docs/client-caching.html):

```kotlin
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(HttpCache)
}
```

In the app I need to implement a refresh feature which will force a request to ignore `Cache-Control` and request fresh data.

How this is possible using ktor?

To get the resources I'm using

```kotlin
private suspend fun HttpClient.getRemote(): List<Foo> = get("https://www.example.com/api_endpoint").body()
```

and I *assume* that I need to specify something in the `get(...)`'s body implementation, but I don't know what.

Comment: So do you want to cache responses for some requests and for some not?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman yes, for example. Another way is to pass a flag to `getRemote` to ignore the current cache and get fresh content

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the current implementation of the `HttpCache` plugin.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I suspected this too

Comment: what is CIO here ? I am not getting option to import.

Comment: @AndroidKiller, is one of the engines behind ktor client. https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html

Comment: @Valerio Thanks for quick response, I will check. But one thing wanted to ask that to enable cache on client side, server api response should have "Cache-Control: Max-Age" in their response header, right ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller yes, that instruct the local cache how to handle the situation. Here's the explanation: https://ktor.io/docs/client-caching.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add `refreshData` parameter to your API function which defaults to `false` (to enable caching), and whenever you want fresh data, just pass `true`, and the current time in milliseconds will be appended as a query to the URL.

```
    suspend fun getDataFromSpreadsheet(
        spreadsheetId: String,
        sheetId: String,
        refreshData: Boolean = false,
    ): ApiResult<String, Any> =
        apiTextResult {
            client.get {
                url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/$spreadsheetId/gviz/tq")
                parameter("gid", sheetId)
                header("X-DataSource-Auth", true)
                if (refreshData) {
                    parameter("refreshData", getTimeMillis())
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This could be a good idea